# Eigen has no output when compiled with mingw-w64

Tags: gcc, eigen, mingw-w64

I am on win10. I just installed mingw-w64  x86_64-7.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0, and copy Eigen3.3.3 to include folder.

Then I add C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\bin to system path.

c++ Hello world works fine.

then I want to check if Eigen works fine, I used the simplest example in Eigen documentation as below

```
~~~
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
int main()
{
  MatrixXd m(2,2);
  m(0,0) = 3;
  m(1,0) = 2.5;
  m(0,1) = -1;
  m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
  std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
~~~
```

However, I found a peculiar thing. I compiled with

g++ eigen_test.cpp

but, running a.exe gives no output at all, and even I append "std::cout << "hello" << std::endl" to the end of the above code , still no output.

But, if I double click the "**mingw-w64.bat**" in mingw-w64 folder, and switch folder by cd, and using the same compilation "g++ eigen_test.cpp". Then it  works!!!!

I really don't understand, because the sole content of mingw-w64.bat is appending C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\bin to %PATH%. But I already add this to my system path.

What is wrong? How to make my eigen work without execute .bat file?

Comment: Does a `std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;` before the Eigen code get printed? Does `Matrix2d` instead of `MatrixXd` work?

Comment: Hi, @chtz, I just figure out what is wrong. running `bat` does have a subtle effect, that is it put mingw path on top of %PATH% and that works. The position in %PATH% matters. Maybe I installed too much software, they interfere with each other cause the problem.